# Where is the old post permalink slug stored?

Tags: posts, permalinks, database, slug

I published an article with permalink slug:

```
http://domain.com/writing
```

Then after publishing, I changed the permalink slug to `writing-lorem`. Now, whenever I visit `/writing`, it redirects to `/writing-lorem`.

I want to use the `writing` slug for a new category but can't, it changes to `writing-2`.

To attempt to remove all records of the `writing` slug, I looked in the DB for the `post_name` column under that post, but the value was the new slug `writing-lorem`.

Then I search for other posts with the `writing` value, none found.

Where exactly is that slug stored and how can I remove it so that I can use it for the category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We determined that the slug was not stored in `postmeta` meta_key `_wp_old_slug`.

In a final attempt to find where this slug is stored. I performed a search for the exact phrase of `writing` and found a few results. The one of interest was in `wp_terms`.

I deleted that entry and then changed the slug of the category to `/writing` and it is working. The strange part was that there were no records within `wp_terms` that connected the post to the slug.

Maybe someone is knowledgeable about this table...

Comment: The `wp_terms` table holds "The categories for both posts and links and the tags for posts". So you must have had a category or tag already using the `writing` slug. Since slugs _must be unique_ across posts/pages/categories/tags Wordpress appends a number to any duplicate, as you found when you changed the slug of your post.

Answer (score 9):

It's in the table `postmeta` with the meta_key of `_wp_old_slug`

If you wanted to clear all of the old slugs you could use this:

`DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug';`

Comment: I searched through that meta_key, did not find the relevant slug. Very strange. Is it possible it can be anywhere else?

Comment: I've been looking through the DB and have only found old slug information in the postmeta table.

Are you 100% sure you changed the old slug? I would navigate to the page/post in the admin section and add the "Slug" area from screen-options to ensure it's actually changed. That's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: It is definitely changed, I double checked. It really baffles me, where else could it possibly be.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of any more help. I have no idea where else to look. Maybe this would help. [Core Issue 12473](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12473) It's only but might be able to shed some light.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I found where the slug was stored, see my answer.