# -2 generated in permalink postname

Tags: permalinks

4
down vote
favorite

I have noticed after deleting an original page in WordPress with lets say a permalink of your_domain.com/contact/ and then trying to recreate the same page with the same name/slug, my WP is generating a "-2" at the end of the link, like: your_domain.com/contact-2/.

I don't understand why, since the original page was deleted. Why is WordPress treating new pages as if the original still exists?
There is nothing in 'trash'.

I repeat there is nothing in 'trash'.

Comment: Was it actually deleted or was it "Trashed". Trashed is just a post-status and the post will still exist until you delete it from your trash.

Comment: Trash is empty already.

Comment: It sounds like you have a similar issue that I had a while back. Please read my question and answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160054/where-is-the-old-post-permalink-slug-stored

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to look in your database and deleted the old entry from there. And then you'll be able to rename the slug to the old name.

Comment: Could anyone expand on that for me please?  I don't want to make the situation worse by poking around in a corrupt database that I know little about.