# Delete Redirect Slug For Specific Post

Tags: redirect, slug

I have a couple of posts that are getting hammered by bots so I want to change the permalink slugs. However, when I do so WP redirects from the old to the new slug. I want the old slug to give a 404. I've managed to find a partial answer in another thread:

"delete the _wp_old_slug post meta entry from the database for that post"

... but I'm having trouble finding _wp_old_slug in phpMyAdmin - I admit I'm no expert with this, so detailed instructions would be very welcome.

~~~~~

UPDATE: I have now discovered the 'Remove Old Slugs' plugin which resolves my problem, but I would still like to know where to look in phpMyAdmin, for my own knowledge.

Comment: If it is stored in the post meta, then you can find it under the `wp_postmeta` table ( assuming your table prefix is `wp_` ). You can use the search feature of PhpMyAdmin. [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/160054/94498)'s a similar question to yours.

Answer (score 1):

The `wp_postmeta` table (all meta tables in WP work similarly) has the following fields:

- `id`: the primary key of the metadata item
- `post_id`: the primary key of the post that this metadata relates to
- `meta_key`: the metadata "key", or name of the metadata
- `meta_value`: the actual metadata value itself

To find old slug entries for a given post (let's assume an id of 123), you would want a query like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM   wp_postmeta
WHERE  meta_key = '_wp_old_slug' AND
       post_id = 123;
```

To delete, just substitute `DELETE` for `SELECT *`.

Comment: Having this kind of generic schema for the table makes it really flexible, but _does_ make it a bit harder to find what you're looking for IME.